# Dart socket.io self signed certificate

Tags: sockets, dart, https, socket.io

I am using this [Dart Socket IO client library](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_common_client). I have set up a Socket.IO server with a self-signed certificate on port 443. When I try to connect, the error message is:

> (OS Error: 
>       CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:352))

How do i get the client or Dart to ignore the error prompt from self-signed certificates?

I know that the NodeJS equivalent of the socket.io allows it by setting the variable **rejectUnauthorized** to false. But it seems [no such variable](https://github.com/moshoujingli/socket.io-client-dart/blob/master/lib/src/engine/socket.dart) in Dart...

This is the code used in Dart to initialize and connect to the server:

```
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('https://localhost', {   
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'reconnectionAttempts': 1,
    'rejectUnauthorized': false
  });
```

Comment: Is the client a browser or another Dart VM?

Comment: The client is currently a Dart project on ubuntu

Comment: Have you consider using dart:io to make the WebSocket connection? You can use "WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket" to upgrade an existing Socket which you can get with SecureSocket.connect which has the possibility to ignore bad certificates: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-io/SecureSocket/connect.html

Comment: I would like to use the features that Socket.IO provide :)